# Using JQuery's Slide effect to hide a block

Tags: jquery

I have a div that I would like to hide with the effect `slideDown`.
I want `slideDown` to hide the text instead of showing it,
and `slideUp` to show the text instead of hiding it.

In other words, the goal is to use the slide animation to hide/show a div. The existing slideUp/Down methods work the opposite way in which I would like to use them.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: http://build-net.co.il/MH/main.html

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

```
$("#myBlockId").toggle()
```

or in case you want an horizontal toggle you should use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function

```
$("#myBlockId").animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

Comment: `toggle` without a duration does not have any animation effect.  With a duration it is not what the question asked for.

Comment: yes, that's true. In jquery website says that the time is 400 by default so I thought it would animate without time.
Sorry and thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery-UI, you can use this to change the direction of the slide.

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
```

Where 1000 is the speed of the animation. You can then use show to reverse the process.

```
$(this).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
```

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate.
http://jsfiddle.net/mtcVC/1/

Comment: I don't see any signature for `hide` or `show` that look even remotely like this.

Comment: Works! there is a problem,
http://build-net.co.il/MH/main.html
the block goes right some how, how can i fixed it?

Comment: How does this work?  Is this part of an extension, maybe jquery UI?

Comment: Thanks for you try, but toggle do the same, it know how to detect the "display" css attirube and choose the right effect for use, for example we have this syntax: $("div").slideToogle(); if the "display" status is "block" it will be used slideDown for hide.

Comment: @ James Montagne,
yes this syntax work with the UI extension that I have connect be4 to the code.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks for the edit - I had seen this used at work or something and didn't realize where it came from.

Comment: @איציקברבי I don't really want to go directly to your site, can you modify/create a jsfiddle that recreates your issue?

Comment: I dont think jsfiddle can show you the problem,
you need fullsize looking..

Comment: You can just use /show after the url to show the whole thing. For example, http://fiddle.jshell.net/mtcVC/1/show/

Comment: the code you have gave me work fine!
but there is a problem, when its sliding down its move right, I dont know why...

Comment: @איציקברבי That is probably because you have a typo in "down" the default action is to move right. Double check spelling/typos. If it says direction: "fown" it will move right, so just re-check.

Comment: I have check the spelling of the syntax and all correct:
$("div#bar div.open").click(function(){
  $("div#Index-2").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
   $("div#bar").hide();
 });

Comment: I'm sorry - but I provided the way to do it. I cannot recreate what you are talking about. I urge you to double-check the syntax again, or paste a jsfiddle that shows the issue.